# Swap cells strings from 2 dataframe columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, compare-and-swap

I'm struggling to swap values from 2 columns of a dataframe as follows:

```
rs649071 rs640249 0.265 0.49 
rs647621 rs640249 0.227 0.34 
rs644339 rs640249 0.116 0.08 
rs641563 rs640249 1.0 33.96 
rs640249 rs11073074 0.248 0.77 
rs640249 rs11637397 0.194 0.68
```

The idea is to test if each cell of column 2 is rs640249 and if not, change to the corresponding string from column 1 and vice-versa. This way the final results would be something like:

```
rs649071 rs640249 0.265 0.49 
rs647621 rs640249 0.227 0.34 
rs644339 rs640249 0.116 0.08 
rs641563 rs640249 1.0 33.96 
rs11073074 rs640249 0.248 0.77 
rs11637397 rs640249 0.194 0.68
```

I was trying to iterate over tuples, however, tuples does not support item assignment.

```
rscode='rs640249'
for inf in LDfiles:
    df = read_csv(inf, sep='\t', skiprows=1, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    for tup in df.itertuples():
        if tup[2] != rscode:
            tup[1], tup[2] = tup[2], tup[1]
        print(tup)
```

Comment: You can transform the tuple to list with `list(tup)` and do the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future refereces, here goes a possible solution:

```
    for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['L1'] == 'rs640249':
            df.set_value(row_index, 'L1' , row['L2'])
            df.set_value(row_index, 'L2' , row['L1'])
```

Best,

Comment: @hayden: thanks for comments, perhaps it's not the best way to go, however, it's working pretty fine. Of course, iterrows will create unnecessary series, nevertheless, I couldn't be able to make things work following your suggestions: I've got null dataframes and a bunch of errors. I suspected about the pandas version (0.8.1) and/or python as well (3.2). Did do you test?

Comment: That's weird. Which pandas and python versions are you using?

Comment: @hayden: If you are interested, have a look in the [errors](http://bpaste.net/show/48868/)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```
def my_fun(row):
    if row['col1'] == 'rs640249':
        return row['col2'], row['col1']
    else:
        return row['col1'], row['col2']

df = df.apply(my_fun, axis=1)
```

If you want to change the values in only one column you can still use `apply`:

```
def my_fun2(row, colID):
    if row[colID][0] == 'rs640249':
        return row[colID][::-1] #reverse the tuple
    else:
        return row[colID]

df[colID] = df.apply(lambda x: my_fun2(x, colID), axis=1)
```

*Note: since `my_fun2` returns a single value, this time `apply` return a Series, so we need to slightly change the way we apply apply.*

Example:

```
df
#                             0
# 0    ('rs649071', 'rs640249')
# 1  ('rs640249', 'rs11073074')

df[0] = df.apply(lambda x: my_fun2(x,0), axis=1)
#                             0
# 0    ('rs649071', 'rs640249')
# 1  ('rs11073074', 'rs640249')
```

Comment: hi hayden, thanks for helping. That's exactly what I you like to do. However, it seems not work for me. I've used index instead because rows are tuples (if row[0]== 'rs...'): row[0], row[1] = row[1], row[0]).

Comment: also, tuples imutable! And that's why things don't go. Problem is still unsolved. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah ha! They are tuples :) Updated, this should fix, also I was missing a `return` in my previous code!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this, with array operations:

```
condition = df['L1'] == 'rs640249'
tmp = df['L1'].copy()
df['L1'][condition] = df['L2'][condition]
df['L2'][condition] = tmp[condition]
```